Firefox moves windows to different monitor after wake up from sleep
Whenever I log back in after my PC has gone to sleep, all my Firefox windows have moved one monitor to the right for some reason.
I have three monitors in total of which one is pretty much always off since its the TV.
Sometimes one of the windows ends up there so I have to use shit+cmd+left to get it back on a monitor which I can actually see.
It seems to only be happening to Firefox, none of the other applications do this.
Does anyone know how I could fix this?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4, Firefox 126.0, Gnome 42.9, and an AMD RX 7800 XT GPU
